# 503 errors not clearing up and not giving any useful information

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I've been getting quite a few of these errors lately. Retrying doesn't seem to clear up the problem. Sometimes recreating the job helps, but frequently it doesn't.

Is there anything I can do to reduce the frequency of this kind of problem? (Project id is 1097390039935)

```
14:37:42.529 URL being requested: https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/bigquery/v2/rest?userIp=2620%3A0%3A102f%3A1004%3A1260%3A4bff%3Afe7c%3A9e95
   I 14:37:42.611 URL being requested: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/1097390039935/jobs/job_PX6Cmd6f3hE551p07zIV7NKnI6Y?alt=json
   I 14:37:42.836 URL being requested: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/1097390039935/queries/job_PX6Cmd6f3hE551p07zIV7NKnI6Y?timeoutMs=30000&startIndex=0&alt=json&maxResults=50
   E 14:37:43.038 HttpError loading bigquery results: {'status': '503', 'content-length': '221', 'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'expires': 'Wed, 18 Jun 2014 21:37:43 GMT', 'server': 'GSE', 'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0', 'date': 'Wed, 18 Jun 2014 21:37:43 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}/{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "Connection error. Please try again."
   }
  ],
  "code": 503,
  "message": "Connection error. Please try again."
 }
}
```

Comment: What errors do you see in App Engine logs (https://appengine.google.com/logs)?

Comment: That's where those logs came from :-). I'm logging those myself, nothing else is logged automatically.